# I want a button in a vertical menu to go down smoothly as shown in screenshot https://ibb.co/nO610e

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, css

I want all category and close button in a vertical menu to go down and up smoothly as shown https://ibb.co/nO610e

https://www.equipus.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the **styles.css** file at below location:

> skin/frontend/alosupermarket/supermarket06/css/styles.css

Update line number **518**

from

```
.custom-menu .vmagicmenu .block-vmagicmenu-content{min-width:270px; max-height:490px; padding-top:11px;margin-top:1px;}
```

to

```
.custom-menu .vmagicmenu .block-vmagicmenu-content{min-width:270px;/*max-height:490px;*/padding-top:11px;margin-top:1px;}
```

And Update line number **2301**

from

```
.all-cat:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(2) {position: relative; top: -29px;}
```

to

```
.all-cat:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(2) {position: relative; /*top: -29px;*/}
```

Comment: WOW!, Thank you @Sukumar Gorai ..working like charm! :)

Comment: Welcome. Happy Coding!